# creating table in sql developer with primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table with primary and foreign keys using following syntax for sql developer but it is not working.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
CREATE Athlete
(
    ATHLETEID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    ATHLETEFIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    ATHLETELASTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    ATHLETEDOB DATE,
    REPCOUNTRY VARCHAR2(12),
    COACHID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ATHLETEID),
    CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_FK FOREIGN KEY (COACHID) REFERENCES COACH(COACHID) 

);
```

Comment: "it isn't working" is not very helpful; please show the actual error you get in future (but fortunately it's pretty clear what's wrong here!).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the TABLE keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE Athlete
(
    ATHLETEID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    ATHLETEFIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    ATHLETELASTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
    ATHLETEDOB DATE,
    REPCOUNTRY VARCHAR2(12),
    COACHID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ATHLETEID),
    CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_FK FOREIGN KEY (COACHID) REFERENCES COACH(COACHID) 

);
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work

just create table first and then try to alter the table

`ALTER TABLE Athlete
ADD CONSTRAINT  ATHLETE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ATHLETEID);`

for foreign key try this

`ALTER TABLE Athlete
ADD CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (COACHID)
  REFERENCES COACH(COACHID);`

Comment: It's creating the table that's the problem... adding the constraints as part of the creation is fine, it's just the missing `TABLE` keyword that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Athlete  (
ATHLETEID CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
ATHLETEFIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20), 
ATHLETELASTNAME VARCHAR2(20), 
ATHLETEDOB  DATE, 
REPCOUNTRY VARCHAR2(12), 
COACHID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ATHLETEID), 
CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_FK FOREIGN KEY (COACHID)    REFERENCES COACH(COACHID)

);
```